# Diophantine Equation Question

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Find all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of rational numbers $x, y$ such that the equations $2x^5 = x^2y^4 + 9y^5$ and $6y^3 = 3x^3 + xy^3$ hold simultaneously.

My try:

Multiplying the second equation by $xy$, we get $6xy^4 = 3x^4y +x^2y^4$

Now substituting $x^2y^4$ in the first equation, we get

$$2x^5 = 6xy^4-3x^4y+9y^5.$$

Rearranging, $2x^5+3x^4y = 6xy^4+9y^5$ so

$$x^4(2x+3y) = 3y^4(2x+3y).$$

You can get a relation between $x$ and $y$ from the last equation and substitute back in any one of the original equation to get real values for $x$ and $y$.

$$(x^4-3y^4)(2x+3y) = 0$$

You will have two relations and substituting back in the original equation will get the real values. Am I right?

Comment: Looks good to me. You can save yourself some trouble by noting that $x^4-3y^4=0$ has no rational solutions.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I noted your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is alright and it's the way to go here, but here's a little note that you should pay attention to. First of all you should assume that $xy \neq 0$, because $0$ is obviously a rational number. After doing this you need to chech the case when $xy = 0$

So after getting $(x^4 - 3y^4)(2x + 3y) = 0$ you get that $2x + 3y = 0$, because as Kevin have noted $x^4 - 3y^4 = 0$ doesn't have a rational solution except for $x=y=0$, but that's not allowed value here.

Sou you can get a relation here:

$$x = \frac{-3y}{2} \forall y \in \mathbb{Q}; y \neq 0$$

The you must check the case when $xy=0$ and assume WLOG that $x=0$, plugging this into the equation we get that $y=0$. Fortunaly if we plug $y=0$ into the relation we derived we would get $x=0$, so we can say:

$$x = \frac{-3y}{2} \forall y \in \mathbb{Q}$$

But sometime it won't be the case so you have to pay attention to that.

Comment: I certainly did not pay attention this detail  Good to know, Thanks

Comment: Actaully you have to pay attention to this everytime you are multiplying both sides of an equality/inequality